# Not sure how to implement this interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

So I'm a little confused about how to implement this interface the right way:

> A MasterMind computer player must, at a minimum, return a valid Guess:

```
public interface MasterMindAI
{
   public Guess nextGuess();
}
```

> **MasterMindAIRandom**
>   The simplest way to implement the interface is to populate the List of
>   color ids with four random integers from 1 to 7 and to return the
>   associated Guess. This is actually a useful class as it allows you to
>   find bugs related to incorporating the AI into the MasterMind game
>   rather than bugs in the AI itself.

So I understand everything about the list and how to populate it. I'm just confused about how to implement the interface the right way. So my MasterMindAIRandom class has to have a method called Guess nextGuess that creates a List of random numbers, yes? But the return type is of type Guess and the List is a list of ints. How exactly am I suppose to return the Guess?

Comment: "four random integers from 1 to 7 and to return the associated Guess."
So you will generate the numbers and each of the numbers are associated with a Guess (like an ID)

Comment: How is Guess defined? Does it take 4 ints or a list of ints, which should contain exactly 4 ints? Guess is not in the standard libs - shall we guess what it is?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, we can only guess :) :

```
import java.util.Random; 

public class MasterMindAIRandom implements MasterMindAI
{
   public Guess nextGuess();
   {
       Random r = new Random ();
       List <Integer> li = new ArrayList <> ();
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
       {
           li.add (r.nextInt (7) + 1); 
       }
       return new Guess (li);
   }
}
```